# CSS Child full height of sticky parent TD

Tags: css, height, sticky

I have a table where the first column's TDs have a position: sticky
And I need to have several child elements, taking up the full height of the cell.

```css
TD:nth-child(1) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
}
SPAN {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD>
    <SPAN>&#x200B;</SPAN><SPAN>&#x200B;</SPAN><LABEL>Other contents</LABEL>
    </TD>
    <TD>Multiline<BR>contents
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Normally I would set position: relative to TD and absolute for SPANs, but I need TD to be sticky.
I'm I missing something?

Using DIVs with display: table-* is not an option, because I need a colspan.

Comment: Does this help? https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/

Answer (score 1):

i don't know, if i understood you correctly, but position of absolute is also working for parents with position sticky. That means, the child will also orientate on the parent althought it has sticky.

All position properties ( sticky, relative and absolute) except for static will make the child orientate to them.

Hop i could help, and not missunderstood you.

Comment: Bah, somehow i missed that